# Screen reader Custom Actions in React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, accessibility

Is it possible to implement custom actions for screen reader in React Native? "for e.g, a shortcut for Add to cart"

Comment: you will need to add more information to this question. Are you asking how to set shortcut keys (and if it is a good idea) or are you after more information, basically what do you mean by a "custom action"?

Comment: [you may find this answer useful about shortcut keys (the section "keyboard shortcut keys" is the relevant bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001087/2702894) as to whether they are a good idea and some implementation concerns. Might be worth reading before considering adding shortcut keys as there is a lot to consider.

Comment: I was referring to the custom voiceover actions on iOS.